# In bash, how do I input a password for a background process command?

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

I'm trying to do an rsync backup from dreamhost to another host, here's the command i'd like to use:

nohup rsync -e "/usr/bin/ssh" --bwlimit=2000 -av username@server.dreamhost.com:remote_directory local_directory&

I'd like the process to keep running in the background and even when I disconnect. Problem is, I don't know how to put in the password when it's a background process. How do I do this?

Comment: Why are you not using a key?

Answer (score 8):

Usually this is done by not requiring a password at all.  Instead, consider configuring SSH to use a public key.  There are several resources online (such as [this one from dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/SSH)) that can help you do that.

Comment: bad advice if you can't change the server

Answer (score 7):

I would use a key. If you need to protect the key with a password or you cannot use a key for whatever reason, then use expect to pass the password:

rsync_auto.sh:

```
#/bin/bash

expect <<<EOF
spawn nohup rsync -e "/usr/bin/ssh" --bwlimit=2000 -av username@server.dreamhost.com:remote_directory
expect "password:"
send "your_password\r"
expect eof
EOF
```

**!!!Make sure that nobody except you can access the file!!!:**

```
chmod 500 rsync_auto.sh
```

A little bit more elaborated way might be to store the password in a keyring application, like gnome-keyring instead of storing them in a plain file. I've found this [article](http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/Store_SSH_passphrases_in_gnome-keyring) if you are interested.

Comment: And realize that whoever can read this file can read the password.

Comment: @Paul yes that's true. But anybody who can read the file can use the key as well. Simply make sure, that the file only readable by the owner

Comment: Agreed, at least ssh client will tell you when your keyfile is, say, world readable and block using it.

Comment: yeah, that's a nice side effect when using keys

Comment: I very rarely downvote answers, but do suggest deleting this one as demonstrating insecure practice is probably worse than saying nothing, especially since the OP didn't say he "cannot use a key".

Comment: @msw As discussed here before, the file will being unaccessible to users except of the owner - as his keyfiles. A hacker who can access the file, can access the keyfiles as well. What is more unsecure now? I can't see it.

Comment: @msw. If you vote to delete my answer, you'll have to delete any answer which will ever suggest using keyfiles for automated authentication, as they are as insecure as my answer, as long as the file with password has proper permissions: `400`, same as for keyfiles. If you need a secure solution: Get up at night, start the backup manually. :D On the other, hand what you are saying is highly misleading as it may let new users think they are safe when using keyfiles.

Comment: I can't vote to delete your answer only downvote it, which I haven't. You're ignoring human factors which says that this script *will* get copied by people who don't understand the vulnerability and don't see your caveat. As Paul noted above, ssh does affirmatively (and centrally) enforce the permissions policy even when the user doesn't understand what they are doing.

Comment: yes, but what if the keyfile is encrypted using a password? My answer is totally correct, as it begins with the suggestion: use a key if possible, and suggest a workaround if it is not possible or they keys are protected by a password. If someone can access the expect script or key files, than security is already deadly broken.